# How to hold terminal open (excepting gnome-terminal)?

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal, profile, terminal-emulator, window

I find useful the gnome-terminal feature of editing (and creating) profiles with the option of holding the terminal open after the command exists.

[image]

(I like to use context menu file manager to run commands to display info about a file in a terminal, to show info in a terminal while processing, etc.)

I wasn't able to find the same feature in other terminals, so I have to install gnome-terminal even when it's not the default terminal.

Are there other terminal emulators with this feature? Is there a command to be used in a given terminal that would have the same effect?

---

I want, with a single line (to be added as context menu entry), to open the terminal, run a command and display info in the terminal window that stays open.   Example: in pantheon-files (elementary os) I add a context menu entry for media info using a contractor file with a line like `Exec=xterm -hold -e "mediainfo -i %f"` (according to a comment below) or `Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "mediainfo -i %f"`.

Comment: Run `tmux` in whatever terminal, then run your command in `tmux`?

Comment: The MacOS `Terminal.app` is one terminal application that has that feature. But I strongly suspect you're not running MacOS!

Comment: xterm has a -hold option - but what other terminal emulators are you using or are familiar with?

Comment: @Celada - yes, this is a linux question; I added the tag now

Comment: @DMcKeon - beside gnome-terminal, I normally use xce4-terminal and pantheon-terminal, but I could install others that would easily include the option. The more basic `xterm -hold` should be posted as answer..

Comment: @lcd047 - I want to open the terminal, run a command and display info in the terminal window that stays open with a single context menu entry.  Example: in pantheon-files (elementary os) I add a context menu entry for media info using a contractor file with a line like `Exec=xterm -hold -e "mediainfo -i %f"` (according to a comment above) or `Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "mediainfo -i %f"`. But running `tmux` and then my command in `tmux` are two separate processes that cannot fit in one context menu entry (`xterm tmux -e "mediainfo -i %f"` would not work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this in any terminal emulator by the simple expedient of arranging for the program not to exit without user confirmation. Tell the terminal to run `terminal_shell_wrapper` which is a script containing something like

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then "${SHELL:-sh}"; else "$@"; fi
echo "The command exited with status $?. Press Enter to close the terminal."
read line
```

If you want any key press to close the terminal change `read line` to

```
stty -icanon; dd ibs=1 count=1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: But how to integrate the terminal running `terminal_shell_wrapper` with it running the command that I want from context menu? Example: in pantheon-files (elementary os) I add a context menu entry for media info using a contractor file with a line like `Exec=xterm -hold -e "mediainfo -i %f"` (according to a comment above) or `Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "mediainfo -i %f"`. How to adjust your solution to a such purpose?

Comment: can i run the script AND my intended command (e.g. `mediainfo -i %f`) with a single command line (which would then be my context menu entry)?

Comment: Add `terminal_shell_wrapper` as a prefix to your command, e.g. `xterm -e terminal_shell_wrapper mediainfo -i %f` is equivalent to `xterm -hold -e mediainfo -i %f`

Answer (score 6):

There are other terminals that have options to keep the terminal open, some by specifying a profile with that setting enabled (just like in **Gnome Terminal**) and some with a specific argument.

### Xterm

`xterm -hold`

from $(man xterm):

-hold Turn on the hold resource, i.e., xterm will not immediately destroy its window when the shell command completes.  It will wait until you use the window manager to destroy/kill the window, or if you use the menu entries that send a signal, e.g., HUP or KILL.

Running `xterm --help`, one of the lines is

`-/+hold                      turn on/off logic that retains window after exit`

To see if other terminals have a similar option, look at their help or man page.

---

### **Konsole**

(default  in KDE):

`konsole --help` shows this line:

`--hold, --noclose         Do not close the initial session automatically when it ends.`

So, the command to use for Konsole will include:

`konsole --hold` or `konsole --nonclose`. It does not need quotation marks. It could be something like:

`Exec=konsole --hold -e  mediainfo -i %f`

---

### Xfce4-terminal

```
Tab Options:
  -x, --execute; -e, --command=command; -T, --title=title;
  --working-directory=directory; -H, --hold
```

So:

`xfce4-terminal -H -e '<command>'`

---

### Terminator

It has an option similar to that in Gnome Terminal, you have to create a profile - e.g. called "hold" - with that option enabled.

To run command and stay open:

`terminator -e '<command>' -p hold`.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_command | cat - /dev/tty
```

...will work with anything, pretty much. If the launcher you use doesn't properly handle pipelines in a command, you might want...

```
sh -c 'some_command | cat - /dev/tty'
```

You can send an interrupt with `CTRL+C` to kill `cat` and end the session, or else just close the terminal window when ready.

Answer (score 0):

why not try guake?
It's always running in background,and when you want to use it,press the hot key it will show up!

[For more detail click here](http://guake.org/)

Comment: You mean I don't need a special option to hold Guake open because it stays open by default. Only that it is also *hidden* by default. I see that `guake -h` says: `-t, --toggle-visibility
                        Toggles the visibility of the terminal window`. But running a command like `Exec=guake -t -e "mediainfo -i %f"` keeps Guake hidden, and I have to make it visible with the shortkey to see the info.  I guess `guake -t` should make it visible if it is not. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Put `$SHELL` at the end of your bash file.